# Botframework V4: Dialogs

Tags: c#, botframework

From what i read from the docs BeginDialogAsync is like pushing from the stack and EndDialogAsync is like popping from the stack. But its not behaving like that in my code.

When i press back to End the dialog in Dialog 3 it goes back to Dialog 1 instead of Dialog 2. Should it go back to dialog 2 because EndDialogAsync popped Dialog 3? Can someone help me and explain too the function of BeginDialogAsync, EndDialogAsync, ContinueDialogAsync, ReplaceDialogAsync, NextAsync. Thank you

Dialog 1

```
    AddStep(async (stepContext, cancellationToken) =>
        {
            var choices = new[] { "Opportunities!" };
            return await stepContext.PromptAsync(
                "choicePrompt",
                new PromptOptions
                {
                    Prompt = MessageFactory.Text($"What can i do for you?"),
                    Choices = ChoiceFactory.ToChoices(choices),
                });
        });

        AddStep(async (stepContext, cancellationToken) =>
        {
            var response = (stepContext.Result as FoundChoice)?.Value;

            if (response == "Opportunities!")
            {
                return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(MainLookAtOppurtinitiesDialog.Id, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
            }
        });
```

Dialog 2 called by Dialog 1's BeginDialogAsync

```
  AddStep(async (stepContext, cancellationToken) =>
        {
            var choices = new[] { "Real Estate", "Mutual Funds" };
            return await stepContext.PromptAsync(
                "choicePrompt",
                new PromptOptions
                {
                    Prompt = MessageFactory.Text($"So {state.Name}, Here are your choices:"),
                    Choices = ChoiceFactory.ToChoices(choices),
                });
        });

        AddStep(async (stepContext, cancellationToken) =>
        {
            var response = (stepContext.Result as FoundChoice)?.Value;

            if (response == "Real Estate")
            {
                return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(MainRealEstateDialog.Id, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
            }

            if (response == "Mutual Funds")
            {
                return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(MainMutualFundsDialog.Id, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
            }

            return await stepContext.ContinueDialogASync();
        });
```

Dialog 3 called by Dialog 2's BeginDialogAsync

```
        AddStep(async (stepContext, cancellationToken) =>
        {
            var choices = new[] { "Continue", "Back" };
            return await stepContext.PromptAsync(
                "choicePrompt",
                new PromptOptions
                {
                    Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Real Estate is what most people invest in first. While deemed a safe investment, please still be wary of factors like: Location, Taxes and Current state of the Economy."),
                    Choices = ChoiceFactory.ToChoices(choices),
                    RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text($"Please choose one of the options."),
                },
                cancellationToken);
        });

        AddStep(async (stepContext, cancellationToken) =>
        {
            var response = (stepContext.Result as FoundChoice)?.Value;

            if (response == "Continue")
            {
                return await stepContext.NextAsync();
            }
            else if (response == "Back")
            {
                return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                return await stepContext.ReplaceDialogAsync(MainRealEstateDialog.Id);
            }
        });
```

When choosing back it goes back to Dialog 1 instead of Dialog 2.

EDIT: this is the whole code and how it is added to dialog context.

```
    public class CalculateMonthlyAmortizations : WaterfallDialog
    {
        public CalculateMonthlyAmortizations(string dialogId, IEnumerable<WaterfallStep> steps = null)
            : base(dialogId, steps)
        {
           AddStep(async (stepContext, cancellationToken) =>
          {
             //..
          });
        }
        public static string Id => "calculateMonthlyAmortizationDialog";

        public static CalculateMonthlyAmortizations Instance { get; } = new CalculateMonthlyAmortizations(Id);
    }
}
```

and

```
        _dialogs = new DialogSet(dialogState);
        _dialogs.Add(CalculateMonthlyAmortizations.Instance);
```

Comment: Can you share more of your code?  I assume you are using ComponentDialogs, but how are these dialogs added to the main DialogSet? and which methods have you over-ridden within each ComponentDialog?

Comment: A good explanation for the basic purpose of these methods can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54103789/86646

Comment: @EricDahlvang I'm using waterfall dialog for each wait sir I'm going to update my code.

Comment: I've tried to re-create your dialog setup, but there is just too much information missing.  Please break this down into a concise repro, and I'll do my best to help.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else has this same question, it sounds like your Dialog 2 is not implementing `ResumeDialofAsync` to catch the return from Dialog 3. In this case, the return rolls up to the next parent, which would be Dialog 1.